# Json data not showing on tableView swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I fetched the data and it is showing when printing but when i try to display it on tableview.Nothing is coming

Am i placing tableview.reloadData in wrong place ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
    tableView.reloadData() 
}


func fetchData()
{     
    if let url = URL(string: urlConstant) {
       
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in
       
            if err == nil
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data
                {
                    do{
                        let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                        
                        guard let array = results.Result as? [Products] else {return }
                 
                        for product in array
                      {
    
                        self.productArray.append(product)
                        }
                     } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()            
    }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `self.tableView.reloadData()` is called to soon, before you do your for loop `self.productArray.append(product)`. You are missing the asynchrone concept. Want to check? Add a print just before your `reloadData()`, and one in your for loop. Check which one is printed before. Also, check that ` self.productArray.append(product)` is even called (parsing went well, etc.)

Comment: @Larme I tried what you said and print before relodData() is getting called first.Where should i use async concept ?

Comment: put some breakpoints in your code to see the order things are executed in.

Comment: Unrelated but delete `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad`. It has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting correct response(check it once) from the server then next thing you need to reload tableView after getting the response from the server and populating the array.

```
func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: urlConstant) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in
                if err == nil
                {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data
                    {
                        do{
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            guard let array = results.Result as? [Products] else {return }
                            for product in array {
                              self.productArray.append(product)
                            }
                            // Reload table view here
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                          }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Alternative, you can add completion handled in fetchData method.

Comment: I tried doing this it is showing UITableview.reloadData() must be used from main thread only

Comment: @Motivationgym5 It will be good to add completionHandler in fetchData(). With this, you can separate UI things from the network calls. Happy coding.