# Rows are empty in tableview swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

So, I am trying to get data from sqlserver to my tableview but I seem to not get it i followed a tutorial and am pretty sure i did nothing wrong i am using a custom cell too, the only thing working is the connection to sql because it prints the data in the output log i am really new to swift and xcode and i have no idea what i am doing.
Anyways here is my code:

**TableCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var idtext: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernametxt: UILabel!
    
    func setText(text: textstuff) {
        idtext.text = text.id
        usernametxt.text = text.username
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var taable: [textstuff] = []

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        taable = createArray()
        
        //Adding the observer for error and to receive the message
       
          }
    
    func createArray() -> [textstuff]{
        var temptext: [textstuff] = []
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(error(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.SQLClientError, object: nil)
               NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(message(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.SQLClientMessage, object: nil)
               
               let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                         client.connect("x.x.x.x", username: "xxxxxx", password: "xxxxxx", database: "xxxxxx") { success in
                         client.execute("SELECT username FROM Supervisors", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                          for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                              for row in table {
                                  for (columnName, value) in row {
                                      print("\(columnName) = \(value)")
                                     let newVal = value as? String ?? ""
                                    let userandid = textstuff(id: columnName, username: newVal)
                                    temptext.append(userandid)
                                    
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          client.disconnect()
                      })
                  }
        return temptext
    }
    
   
  
    @objc func error(_ notification: Notification?) {
     let code = notification?.userInfo?[SQLClientCodeKey] as? NSNumber
     let message = notification?.userInfo?[SQLClientMessageKey] as? String
     let severity = notification?.userInfo?[SQLClientSeverityKey] as? NSNumber
     if let code = code, let severity = severity {
         print("Error #\(code): \(message ?? "") (Severity \(severity))")
     }
 }

    @objc func message(_ notification: Notification?) {
        let message = notification?.userInfo?[SQLClientMessageKey] as? String
        print("Message: \(message ?? "")")
    }
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
       
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taable.count
       }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let text = taable[indexPath.row]
               
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell") as! TableCell
               
               
               cell.setText(text: text)
               
               return cell
    }
    
    
       
   }
```

**textstuff.swift**

```
import Foundation
class textstuff{
    
    var id: String
    var username: String
    
    init(id: String, username: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
    }
    
}
```

I would really appreciate any help guys!!

**EDIT**
I tried printing `taable.count` and as expected it printed 0

Comment: Yes if taable.count is 0, your table will be empty. Try putting some dummy data into taable to see that your table view works, then you can work on why you're not getting the data you expect into the array.

Comment: @Corbell sorry i am super new to swift...
How can i add dummy data?

Comment: Also I'd recommend calling your data array something besides 'taable', pretty confusing naming scheme. What about something like "textData"?

Comment: @Corbell that is a great idea actually

Comment: @Corbell just changed the name,
But how can i add dummy data?

Comment: var textData: [String] = ["dummy-1", "dummy-2", "dummy-3"] when you declare it, then in your cell.setText() line you'll be setting those values to display in the table. This is not really a Swift or TableView problem just basic programming - create mock content for your UI before trying to hook up to other data sources.

Comment: Have you set delegate and datasource? If not, then set tableview.delegate = self and tableview.datasource = self in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @Nexus i have done it in the storyboard

Comment: After the assignment of your array reload tableview after this line:- taable = createArray(). And try to print your temptext array. It may be returning before assignment.

Comment: @Nexus i tried reloading the table after creating array but still the same problem and my temptext prints this:
[TookyStores.textstuff]
[TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff]
[TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff]
[TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff, TookyStores.textstuff]

Note:TookyStores is my project name

Comment: @Nexus i already did it why would i do it again??

Comment: @Nexus okay i have added this
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell", for indexPath: indexPath) as! TableCell` Instead of this:  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell") as! TableCell`

But now it gives an error saying `Expected expression in list of expressions`

Comment: @Corbell i tried adding dummy data but still nothing appears maybe the problem is with the table??

Comment: Refer this:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/62863848/5603274

Comment: @Nexus Still nothing tried every single thing but it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are caught in the asynchronous trap. You cannot return something from a asynchronous task as return value of a method. The returned array will always be empty.

In this case the solution is quite easy. At the end of the completion handler assign the result to the data source array and reload the table view.

Replace `viewDidLoad` with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createArray()
}
```

Replace `createArray` with

```
func createArray() {
    var temptext: [textstuff] = []
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(error(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.SQLClientError, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(message(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.SQLClientMessage, object: nil)
           
    let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
    client.connect("x.x.x.x", username: "xxxxxx", password: "xxxxxx", database: "xxxxxx") { success in
        client.execute("SELECT username FROM Supervisors", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
             for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                 for row in table {
                     for (columnName, value) in row {
                         print("\(columnName) = \(value)")
                         let newVal = value as? String ?? ""
                         let userandid = textstuff(id: columnName, username: newVal)
                         temptext.append(userandid)
                                
                     }
                 }

             }
             self.taable = temptext
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableview.reloadData()
             }
             client.disconnect()
        })
    }
}
```

And please conform to the naming convention and name structs and classes with starting uppercase letter (`Textstuff`)

Comment: Bro you are such a life saver
Thank you so much!!!!